# Printing a dictionary value of a function in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a looping function that prompts the user to enter a key from the first function and if it is is a key then it prints its value. If the word entered is not in the dictionary it returns "No entry".

What I have so far.

```
def read_ticker():
    c = {}
    with open('tickers.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = [item.strip('"').strip() for item in line.split(",")]
            c[items[0]] = items[1:]

    print(c)

read_ticker()

d = read_ticker()

def ticker():

    x = input('Ticker: ')
    if x in d:
        return x[c]
    else:
        return 'No entry'
ticker()
```

How can I return the value of the key entered in the second function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your read_ticker() function should return c:

```
def read_ticker():
    c = {}
    with open('tickers.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = [item.strip('"').strip() for item in line.split(",")]
            c[items[0]] = items[1:]

    print(c)
    return c
```

and then you can modify your ticker function as follows:

```
def ticker():
    x = input('Ticker: ')
    if x in d.keys():
        return d[x]
    else:
        return 'No entry'
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! One more question, how would I get it to loop the input?

Comment: Put it in a for or while loop and please accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You never return your dictionary in `read_ticker`, and it's unclear why you're calling the function twice.

Where `print(c)` is put `return c`.

And I think you want to index the dict instead of indexing the input.

Also, what is `c` that you're indexing with? This is undefined. I'm assuming this is meant to be the dictionary as defined in `read_ticker`. In which case you want `d[x]`.

The dictionary `c` isn't global, although you could define it to be, so you can't access it in your other function by `c` (ignoring that the indexing is backwards even if possible). Instead, since the dictionary is local to the function `read_ticker` and modified there we return the dictionary and store it in the variable `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Your ticker function can use [get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which allows you to give a value if the key doesn't exist, like this:

```
def ticker():
    x = input('Ticker: ')
    return d.get(x, "No entry")
```